Finiteness of graph satisfying a certain subgraph condition
Let $G$ be a directed graph with a proper edge coloring $c: E(G) \to [n]$. Assume every $2$-colored subgraph of $G$ is isomorphic to the following graph depicted below

Is $G$ finite? My thought is that this graph is isomorphic to some directed version of an $n$-dimensional hypercube and hence is finite but I haven’t been able to prove this. Any help is appriciated!

Just for clarification, do you mean every induced $2$-colored subgraph, is isomorphic, to the graph you sketched?

@Immi yes, exactly. Pick two colors, then the subgraph induced by the edges of those two colors should have connected components isomorphic to the graph I sketched.

Do you also want your graph to be connected? Otherwise you could take infinitely many disjoint copies of the $n$-hypercube. I think I know how to direct it and color the hypercube s.t. one cube satisfies your condition, and then taking infinitely many of those.
Now if you assume $G$ to be connected, I think you can prove finiteness via induction on $n$.
The idea goes as follows: (might be incorrect, I have zero experience with infinite graphs, please be nice if it's nonsense)
The base case $n=2$ is clear with our connectedness assumption and we can even say that it's isomorphic to a certain directed $2$-hypercube.
Our inductive hypothesis is that any connected, directed graph with an $n-1$-coloring and the "subgraph" condition is finite.
Now suppose you take a connected, directed graph $G$ with $n\ge 3$ as in your description of the task. Deleting all edges of color $n$ yields potentially infinitely many connected components, which all satisfy our conditions for the inductive hypothesis to hold with $n-1$-colors, and are therefore finite!
Let us consider such a finite component $H$. There exists a vertex $v\in H$, which has an adjacent edge colored in color $n$ and going in between $H$ and some other component $H_{v}$. The idea is now to show that all other vertices in $H$ see a $n$ colored edge going in between $H$ and $H_v$. Notice that any vertex $u$ in $H$ must see exactly one edge colored in $n$, but where this edge connects to is not clear a priori.
Now for this notice that between any adjacent vertices $u,v \in H$ (same $v$ as before) it must hold that $H_u = H_v$ because our "subgraph" condition. But then since $H$ is connected all vertices in $H$ have exactly one $n$-colored neighbour going into another component $H'= H_v$.
This means there could have only been the two connected components $H$ and $H'$ to begin with.
Meaning $G$ has $|H|+|H'|$ vertices and is therefore finite, because both $|H|,|H'|$ are finite.
This is by no means a full proof, but maybe the idea can be useful.

Awesome. Nice induction!
